# How to use BufferedReader in a try catch?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I've been trying to use bufferedreader several times but every time I get some form error. This is time it is "not a statement" and "; expected" also "catch without try". I keep getting errors at the line with the try(bufferedreader) line. Am I using this correct? I am just trying it out and not quite sure how it works. from the online resource I've been looking at my code looks fine. But when I run my own it gives me errors.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Problem2 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        if(args.length != 1){
            System.out.println("Please enter a txt file");
        }
        else{
            String s;
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(New FileReader(args[0]))) {
                while ( (s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] words = s.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
                    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                        //code
                        }
                    }
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `New FileReader` should be `new FileReader`

Comment: What is this `}` under `//code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The errors are simple, firstly you're supposed to use `new FileReader` (with lowercase `n`) rather than `New FileReader` (with uppercase `N`).

2) you're closing the `else` block before attaching the `catch` handlers to the `try` block.

I have now corrected both issues and the code below should compile.

```
if(args.length != 1){
     System.out.println("Please enter a txt file");
}
else{
    String s;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
      while ( (s = br.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] words = s.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
         for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
           //code
         }
      }
      br.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
         System.out.println(ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `br.close();` if you use  **try-with-resources** statement:

`try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0])))`